# Makefile -l command in the target prerequisites or in the instruction to make the target?

Tags: makefile

I want to know, if I'm going to use -l command, it should be used in the prerequisites as follows?:

```
tarea1: tarea1.o operations.o -ldisplay -lmatrix
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

or in the instruction to make the target as below?:

```
tarea1: tarea1.o operations.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -ldisplay -lmatrix
```

I've been told that it should be like the last example (in the instruction), because I only use libmatrix.a and libdisplay.a (I don't make them), but I have the makefile like in the first way and it's just works fine, but if I try to do it like the last example I get this error...

```
gcc  -o tarea1 tarea1.o operations.o -ldisplay -lmatrix
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldisplay
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmatrix
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tarea1] Error 1
```

Should I make it as in the first example (that is what I have in my makefile) or try to do it as the second way (and try to make it work)?.

Greetings.

Comment: I don't know how the first way is working for you, since I would expect it to treat `-ldisplay` and `-lmatrix` as targets to be built. Where are `lindisplay.a` and `libmatrix.a`, and how do you build them?

Comment: Just saw your other question, which partially answers my question. Try this: `make libdisplay.a`, then `make libmatrix.a`, then try the second way, but with `$(CC) -o $@ $^ -L. -ldisplay -lmatrix`, and tell us the result.